# Javascript function say not declared?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Writing some fairly basic html .. when i try to click the button nothing happenes .. but an error is logged in my console as speakenglish is not defined

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Language Translator</title>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function speakenglish() {
            var ddl = document.getElementById("ispeakenglish");
            var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
                if (selectedValue === "selectlanguage") {
                alert("Please select a answer");
                }
                if (selectedValue === "speakenglishno") {
                alert("Sorry to partake in our service you will need to be able to speak english");
                }
                if (selectedValue === "speakenglishyes")
                { 
                    location.replace({% static '/page2.html' %});
                }
     }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Basic Language Translator</h1>
    <p> A Userbase generated language translator </p>
    <label class="languespoken" for="ispeakenglish">Do you know English?</label>
    <select id="cardtype" name="cards">
        <option value="selectlanguage">--- Please select ---</option>
        <option value="speakenglishyes">Yes</option>
        <option value="speakenglishno">No</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" onclick="speakenglish()" value="Proceed">

</body>
```

Comment: Hi guys just explaining the ({% static '/page2.html' %}); it was for an IDE and that was how to call other pages .... i can change it but its irrelevant in the fact .... that page is not getting called at all (because the function isnt running) if its getting called and i will definately get an error saying this page isnt valid i will change it to a valid one ( which currently doesnt exist)

Comment: Best practice is to avoid assigning functions with inline attributes. Give the button an `id="yourIdName"` attribute instead and put a corresponding function call at the bottom of the `body`: `<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('yourIdName').addEventListener('click', speakenglish, false);</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Language Translator</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function speakenglish() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById("cardtype");
        var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
            if (selectedValue === "selectlanguage") {
            alert("Please select a answer");
            }

            if (selectedValue === "speakenglishno") {
            alert("Sorry to partake in our service you will need to be able to speak english");
            }
            if (selectedValue === "speakenglishyes")
            { 
                //location.replace({% static '/page2.html' %}); //change It
                window.location = 'page2.html';
            }
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Basic Language Translator</h1>
<p> A Userbase generated language translator </p>
<label class="languespoken" for="ispeakenglish">Do you know English?</label>
<select id="cardtype" name="cards">
    <option value="selectlanguage">--- Please select ---</option>
    <option value="speakenglishyes">Yes</option>
    <option value="speakenglishno">No</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="speakenglish()" value="Proceed">
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it ... now i need to figure out why

Comment: Downvoter be careful ............!!

Comment: Thanks @sleepingGgod anytime ...... you did one mistake next line of your function definition. Take look in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Change `id`

```
 var ddl = document.getElementById("cardtype");
```

because you in there page there is not id *ispeakenglish*.

Also could you explain what this code does `location.replace({% static '/page2.html' %});` ?

Answer (score 1):

it's because you don't have any element with `ispeakenglish` id. so the function has error.

```
TypeError: ddl is null
```

quick solution would be to replace

```
var ddl = document.getElementById("ispeakenglish");
```

with

```
var ddl = document.getElementById("cardtype");
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
 location.replace({% static '/page2.html' %});
```

you have a syntax error. Hence the `<script>` tag can not be parsed and the function remains undefined.

I'm not sure, what you want to do there, so I can't fix it. In case this should just be a redirect, you probably want to use:

```
 window.location = '/page2.html';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your function declaration :

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id
location.replace({% static '/page2.html' %});
```

Fix it and your function will work fine :)